# Runtime error 3134 insert into statement-User Form

Tags: vba, ms-access

Am developing an Employee Daily time tracker which include a Userform and Table, I want Employees to fill the form and hit a add button to send the data from from to table. I have written the following code, which is throwing an error:

```
runtime error 3134 insert into statement
```

The code is as below:

```
Private Sub ADD_Click()
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO utilizationdata(DU-Date, [FirstName], US_Tax_Group)" & _
                  "VALUES(" & Me.Text5 & ",'" & Me.Text7 & "'," & _
                  Me.Combo25 & ",)"

PrForm.Form.Requery

End Sub
```

[Screenshot of userform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFJH3.jpg)

Comment: Not enough information to say for sure, but for one, you have a comma before the final bracket that shouldn't be there, and your first field looks like a date, which may have to be converted from string to date, and delimited with #.

Comment: Build your SQL statement into a string variable and then use Debug.Print to dump it to the Immediate Window. One of the most important steps you can learn in troubleshooting. Sometimes it's not what you think - and running it in a SQL View window will often identify the specific problem spot - like the extra comma @PhillipXT pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose DU-Date into brackets: [DU-Date]

Also, probably, you need to enclose in "#" date, remove coma and add spaces:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO utilizationdata ([DU-Date], [FirstName], [US_Tax_Group]) " & _
                  "VALUES(#" & Me.Text5 & "#,'" & Me.Text7 & "'," & _
                  Me.Combo25 & ")"
```

And it's easier to build the query in query builder, then replace data by variables.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help, but when i used the code mentioned you am getting an new run time error 3075 missing operator. Please help

Comment: Please give us SQL statement with data as suggested @dbmitch in comments to your question and let us know what are fields data types. Without this it's difficult to understand. For instance this error may appear if Me.Text5 or Me.Combo25 empty.